# People need to meet once - table propagation

Tags: sql-server, excel, propagation

I have a list of 33 persons, they need to meet once with everybody, I have specific dates that meeting can happen.
How can i poropagate those dates in table ?

I do not have to make this in mssql, it can be excel even

Would be very pleasd for some feedback how to solve this problem, doing this by hand seems to be waste of time and to be honest not that simple

I have something like this for now:

`````
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20210426'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20210510'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20210524'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20210607'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20210621'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20210705'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20210719'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20210802'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20210816'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20210830'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20210913'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20210927'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20211011'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20211025'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20211108'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20211122'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20211206'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20211220'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20220103'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20220117'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20220131'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20220214'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20220228'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20220314'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20220328'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20220411'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20220425'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20220509'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20220523'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20220606'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20220620'
insert into @Tdate ( data ) select '20220704'

select * from @tdate

declare @tperson table ( lp int identity(1,1), person varchar(120), 
[AA] date, [AB] date, [AC] date, [AD] date, [AE] date, [AF] date, [AG] date, [AH] date,
[AI] date, [AJ] date, [AK] date, [AL] date, [AM] date, [AN] date, [AO] date, [AP] date,
[AR] date, [AS] date, [AT] date, [AU] date, [AW] date, [AX] date, [AY] date, [AZ] date,
[BA] date, [BB] date, [BC] date, [BD] date, [BF] date, [BE] date, [BG] date, [BH] date,
[BI] date )

insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AA'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AB'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AC'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AD'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AE'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AF'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AG'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AH'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AI'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AJ'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AK'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AL'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AM'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AN'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AO'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AP'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AR'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AS'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AT'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AU'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AW'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AX'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AY'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'AZ'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'BA'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'BB'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'BC'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'BD'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'BF'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'BE'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'BG'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'BH'
insert into @tperson ( person )
select 'BI'


update @tperson set [AA] = '21000101' 
update @tperson set [AB] = '21000101' where lp >= 2
update @tperson set [AC] = '21000101' where lp >= 3
update @tperson set [AD] = '21000101' where lp >= 4
update @tperson set [AE] = '21000101' where lp >= 5
update @tperson set [AF] = '21000101' where lp >= 6
update @tperson set [AG] = '21000101' where lp >= 7
update @tperson set [AH] = '21000101' where lp >= 8
update @tperson set [AI] = '21000101' where lp >= 9
update @tperson set [AJ] = '21000101' where lp >= 10
update @tperson set [AK] = '21000101' where lp >= 11
update @tperson set [AL] = '21000101' where lp >= 12
update @tperson set [AM] = '21000101' where lp >= 13
update @tperson set [AN] = '21000101' where lp >= 14
update @tperson set [AO] = '21000101' where lp >= 15
update @tperson set [AP] = '21000101' where lp >= 16
update @tperson set [AR] = '21000101' where lp >= 17
update @tperson set [AS] = '21000101' where lp >= 18
update @tperson set [AT] = '21000101' where lp >= 19
update @tperson set [AU] = '21000101' where lp >= 20
update @tperson set [AW] = '21000101' where lp >= 21
update @tperson set [AX] = '21000101' where lp >= 22
update @tperson set [AY] = '21000101' where lp >= 23
update @tperson set [AZ] = '21000101' where lp >= 24
update @tperson set [BA] = '21000101' where lp >= 25
update @tperson set [BB] = '21000101' where lp >= 26
update @tperson set [BC] = '21000101' where lp >= 27
update @tperson set [BD] = '21000101' where lp >= 28
update @tperson set [BF] = '21000101' where lp >= 29
update @tperson set [BE] = '21000101' where lp >= 30
update @tperson set [BG] = '21000101' where lp >= 31
update @tperson set [BH] = '21000101' where lp >= 32
update @tperson set [BI] = '21000101' where lp >= 33


-- juz odbyte
update @tperson set [AB] = '20210426' where lp = 1
update @tperson set [AE] = '20210426' where lp = 4
update @tperson set [AJ] = '20210426' where lp = 8
update @tperson set [AK] = '20210426' where lp = 3
update @tperson set [AS] = '20210426' where lp = 16
update @tperson set [AT] = '20210426' where lp = 12
update @tperson set [AU] = '20210426' where lp = 17
update @tperson set [AY] = '20210426' where lp = 7
update @tperson set [AZ] = '20210426' where lp = 14
update @tperson set [BA] = '20210426' where lp = 21
update @tperson set [BB] = '20210426' where lp = 13
update @tperson set [BC] = '20210426' where lp = 6
update @tperson set [BD] = '20210426' where lp = 15
update @tperson set [BE] = '20210426' where lp = 29
update @tperson set [BG] = '20210426' where lp = 22
update @tperson set [BI] = '20210426' where lp = 32

update @tperson set [AC] = '20210510' where lp = 1
update @tperson set [AF] = '20210510' where lp = 4
update @tperson set [AZ] = '20210510' where lp = 7

SELECT * FROM @TPERSON ````
`````

Answer (score 0):

Excel VBA would be a good option. Create a list of strings for each person, then create a for each loop on this list and a for each loop within each for each loop to make every person meet with every person. Exclude meetings that have allready been set-up.

```
Dim Persons as list of string
Persons.add("Employee1")
Persons.add("Employee2")

Dim Person as string
Dim PersonToMeet as string

Dim Meetings as list of string
Dim MeetingsWithDates as list of string
Dim Meeting as string
Dim LastDateUsed as Datetime = "01-01-2022"

For each Person in Persons
    For each PersonToMeet in Persons
        If (Person != PersonToMeet) then
            Meeting = Person + " meets " + PersonToMeet
            if not (Meetings.contains(meeting)) then
                Meetings.add(meeting)
                Set LastDateUsed = DateAdd(LastDateUsed,D,1)
                MeetingsWithDates.add(meeting + " at " + LastDateUsed.ToString())
            end if
        end if
    Next
Next
```

Lastly, print the strings in MeetingsWithDates to a defined range.

You need to do some code-debugging, this is just a rough example that will not work out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanks, that was interesting, but I found a way with out using VBA in this article: https://dhexcel1.wordpress.com/2017/06/02/using-excel-to-make-a-round-robin-tournament-schedule-by-david-hager/